# why can't we use binomial theorem to expand this expression

Tags: matrices, recreational-mathematics, binomial-theorem

I was recently told that while expanding expressions of the form

$$(A+B)^n$$

where A and B are square matrices of same order and n is a natural number then

$$(A+B)^n =$$ 
 $$ {{n}\choose{0}}A^{0}B^{n} +{{n}\choose{1}}A^{1}B^{n-1} +....+{{n}\choose{n}}A^{n}B^{0}$$

can be done only if $$AB=BA$$ holds true.

I don't know why it's not true in general and think that $(A+B)^2=A^2+B^2+AB+BA $ might hold some clue. kindly help me out.

Comment: $AB$ is not $BA$ in general

Comment: The binominal coefficient would be incorrect.   It counts the $AB$ branches of the tree diagram the same as $BA$ branches which is only true if we have a commutative algebra.

Comment: Commutativity is needed for application of binomial formula. On a commutative korper in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the answer already, it seems to me.  You know that $$(A+B)^2=A^2+B^2+AB+BA\tag1$$  If the proposed formula is true in the $n=2$ case then $$(A+B)^2=A^2+B^2+2AB\tag2$$ Comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$ we see $$AB=BA$$

Doesn't this answer the question?